# Url Passthrough with Cloudpages

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have been getting "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error" every time I try to pass data through the url of one of my CloudPages.

I even tried taking the url and just adding &test=test and it still gives me the same error. Is this not possible with the generated url from Cloudpages?

The idea of what I'm doing is passing data from an email into a landing page.

EDIT: The page does work without any additions to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add code in the CloudPage to actually do something with those URL parameters, but at this stage it shouldn't stop the page from loading.

For the error you are receiving, it looks as though you may be missing a quotation mark (?). That needs to be appended to the end of the standard URL before you start listing out your extra parameters.

Example: http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/dfg78sdf7gsd?test=test&test2=test2&[...]